# Поток и кнопка Java

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как грамотно реализовать в потоке ожидание нажатия кнопки.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

        class Button {
        static JButton button1 = new JButton("iuo"); }

        class ButtonListener1 extends Button implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button1.setText("Привет");
            Font BigFontTR = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 100);
            button1.setFont(BigFontTR);
        } }


        class SomeThing extends ButtonListener1 implements Runnable {
            public void run() { 
                  // Как сделать так, чтобы поток ждал нажатия на кнопку?
            }
        }


        public class Jitik extends SomeThing {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jitik");
                frame.setSize(800, 1000);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
                frame.add(panel);
                panel.add(button1);
                button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener1());
                frame.setVisible(true);

                SomeThing mThing = new SomeThing();
                Thread myThready = new Thread(mThing);  
                myThready.start();
                myThready.join();

                String s = button1.getText();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вы уверенны, что останавливать поток это действительно то, что вам нужно? Почему бы просто не создавать новый поток уже в обработчике нажатия в момент нажатия?

Comment: Программой создается кнопка, нажимаю на кнопку изменяется надпись на кнопке, затем эту надпись нужно считать. Так как все в 1 потоке, считывание надписи с кнопки происходит быстрее ее нажатия. Поэтому создаю новый поток, до выполнения которого программа не сможет считать надпись на кнопке. Но я не могу понять как в методе run() заставить программу ждать пока я не нажму на кнопку.

Comment: опишите задачу, а не решение. что делает кнопка? зачем надо ждать определенное время?

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю: Вы изменяете текст кнопки в обработчике нажатия на `button1.setText("Привет")` и не знаете как получить `Привет` ?

Comment: Какой смысл изменять текст и сразу же его получать? Ну допишите после `button1.setFont(BigFontTR);` `String text = button.getText();`

Comment: Делаюю крести нолики в Swinge. И мне нужно считать с кнопок надписи, чтобы сделать проверку на выигрыш и проигрыш. Так как это все в 1 потоке, программа считвает надписи быстрее чем нажаты кнопки.